# What can i do if my GDPR requests are being ignored?

Tags: privacy, gdpr

I have requested my personal data removal from one shady company that has gotten to my email somehow.

They said they've complied, but i am still getting newsletters from them.

What can i do as a consumer now? What authorities can i contact if my requests are being ignored? Can i report the company somewhere?

Comment: If you [edit] the question to include where you are, we can point you at the relevant website.

Comment: @MartinBonner Or we just link the directory :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_data_protection_authority

Comment: @Luc *Much* better idea - then it becomes relevant to all future readers.  (Sadly, I can't +1 your edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; take it up with your national GDPR agency. Every EU member has one (see [this list of DPAs on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_data_protection_authority)). In some countries such as Germany, you need to contact agency in your state. If a company is getting complaints from multiple countries, the GDPR agencies will among themselves appoint a lead investigator, but you don't need to care about that.

Comment: funny thing, now i'm being ignored by my national data protection authority